# Как посчитать количество знаков ДО запятой?

Tags: javascript

Не нашел ни одного удобного решения. Я представляю, что нужно делить на 10, 100, 1000, … , но надеюсь, что есть уже стандартная функция, которая позволит вернуть число знаков до запятой.

Вы такую знаете?)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Да, есть, эта функция - десятичный логарифм с округлением в меньшую сторону.

Как следует из определения данной функции - логарифм это показатель степени, в которую нужно возвести основание логарифма, чтобы получить аргумент.

В случае с десятичным логарифмом(логарифмом по основанию 10) - то, в какую степень нужно возвести 10, чтобы получить аргумент.

UPD: после комментария господина @Akina и добавления ограничений ответ чуть усложнился:

```js
let count = n => {
  n = 1 + Math.log10(n*n) / 2;
  return Math.max(n - n % 1, 1);
};
console.log(count(10230.4)); // 5
console.log(count(-0.0000004)); // 1 
console.log(count(-1.4)); // 1
console.log(count(NaN)); // NaN

console.log("---"); 

let numberCount = n => 1 + Math.max(Math.floor(Math.log10(Math.abs(n))), 0);
console.log(numberCount(1023.4)); // 4
console.log(numberCount(-0.004)); // 1 
console.log(numberCount(-1.4)); // 1
console.log(numberCount(NaN)); // NaN
```

——-

Так же можно работать со строкой, пожалуй этот метод будет короче всего:

```js
let numberCount = n => Math.abs(n).toFixed().length;
console.log(numberCount(1023.4)); // 4
console.log(numberCount(-0.004)); // 1
console.log(numberCount(1.4)); // 1
console.log(numberCount(NaN)); // 3
```

——-

Рекурсивный метод:

```js
let numberCount = (n,c) => Math.abs(n) < 1 ? (c||1) : numberCount(n/10, (c||0)+1);
console.log(numberCount(1023.4)); // 4
console.log(numberCount(-0.004)); // 1
console.log(numberCount(1.4)); // 1
console.log(numberCount(NaN)); // stack overflow
```

PS: и в любом случае не понятно что делать с `NaN`

Comment: Для, скажем, `0.004` код вернёт -2, что в общем неверно - товарищ просит количество знаков до запятой, а не порядок числа. Т.е. если код даёт менее +1, следует подкорректироваться и вернуть-таки +1 (возможная вариация - нужно количество значащих цифр до десятичного разделителя, тогда не +1, а ноль).

Comment: @Akina, да спасибо за замечание, сейчас подтяну

Comment: Вариант с `.toFixed()` самый прозрачный.

Comment: @РустамГимранов да, но не такой интересный из-за переносимости

Answer (score 1):

```js
    var rest = -123123.12312
    if (isNaN(rest)){
      console.log("NaN")
    }else {
      var c = "" + rest
      var ce = c.split('.')
      var ress = ce[0].replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')
      console.log(ress.length)
    }
```

Примитивно))

Comment: добавьте отрицательные числа и NaN и будет не так примитивно :)

Comment: и да, не во всех локалях разделитель это точка

Comment: Вот тут кажется всё учел)

Comment: `String( parseInt( rest ) ).replace("-","").length` — тоже вариант))

Comment: хороший вариант! но я бы оставил replace вот так (/[^0-9]/g, '')

Comment: Изначальный вариант ответа больше нравился, все остальное - это надуманные другими участниками условности. Все эти условности нужно проверять и откидывать до такого как узнавать количество знаков до запятой.

Comment: @РустамГимранов согласен, с дополнениями не так красиво

Answer (score 0):

Еще вариант простого решение этой задачи

```
function lenSymbolBeforeDot(num){
   let res = 0;

   if(isNaN(num) || !isFinite(num)){ // Проверяем, число ли
      return -1;
   }
   let getNum = String(num).match(/^-?([0-9]+)/);

   if(getNum && getNum[1]) 
      res = getNum[1].length;

   return res;
}
```

Comment: 1.не работает из-за опечаток.  2. почему не сниппет? 3.тогда уж и на Infinity надо проверять

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, поправил 1 и 3. Хотя проверку на NaN можно и не делать. Функция вернет 0 и это отвечает на вопрос ( сколько цифр перед запятой). Ну насчет второго не очень понял

Answer (score 0):

```
str.split(',').map(some => '${some}(${some.length})`)
```